# What the criteria of power factor correction capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, power-factor-correction

I'm thinking of selecting a load with active power less than 200W and PF<0.5 for my school assignment to show the result of current usage before and after power factor correction. There are different type of capacitor in market, specifically the polarity and non polarity type. Is any non polarity type capacitor can be classified as power factor correction capacitor? Example the one sold in the website. https://shopee.com.my/CP--4uF-5uF-6uF-8uF-10uF-12uF-15uF-16uF-20uF--450v-AC-Industrial-Fan-Capacitor-Motor-Start-Run-Kapacitor-i.95888842.2872585832?gclid=Cj0KCQjwwJuVBhCAARIsAOPwGASgFnA_LnvywYTs12iU-SuyMm8joxrGZxWxtFXds31HaNvZiB9eZ2MaAl84EALw_wcB or the type of capacitor must be specifically written how many "KVAR"? I'm using a 240VAC supply.

Comment: It needs to be placed behind a fuse if it’s not X-rated. Check that it has an AC voltage rating sufficiently high enough for your system.

Comment: OK a fuse is indeed a good suggestion, but in this case, the capacitor able to sustain 450VAC, I'm connecting it in parallel with a load driving with 240VAC, the fuse is still needed?

Comment: Good! If your product already have a fuse, just place the capacitor downstream of it.

Comment: I don't think it's a specific type. Polarized types will not work for you because it's AC.

Comment: The use of a capacitor may not help with the load you are trying to correct. You mentioned "active" so I suspect a electronic power supply of some sort. The issue here is the poor power factor is due to current distortion not a lagging current as happens with some electrical loads like AC motors.